# python3 comment went wrong in url file

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-urls

I am new in python3, and I used django to create a web. However, when I wrote url file, I used '''comment here''' as comment instead of #. And it went wrong, with this error.

```
path('photo/',views.indexPhoto, name="indexPhoto"),
   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here is the code with comment

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index, name="index"),
    '''comment here'''
    path('photo/',views.indexPhoto, name="indexPhoto"),
    path('photo/add/',views.addPhoto, name="addPhoto"),
    path('photo/insert',views.insertPhoto, name="insertPhoto"),
]
```

When I delete the '''comment here''', then the project works, and I can view the web page.

I am not sure why it happens, anyone help?

Comment: Please explain your lines of code so other users can understand its functionality. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `'''` are not actually comments.

They are something called as Document Strings. They are evaluated by the interpreter(as strings) and NOT ignored like `#comments`.

You can read more about doc string here

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/

---

In your case, you are assigning an extra string value to Url paths array hence giving you an error.
Read more in detail
https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/505ba3cfc6addb000200e33c
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#block-comments

Comment: Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

You can not comment like ''' ''' in URLs.

you can use # for comments. Like

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index, name="index"),
    # comment here
    path('photo/',views.indexPhoto, name="indexPhoto"),
    path('photo/add/',views.addPhoto, name="addPhoto"),
    path('photo/insert',views.insertPhoto, name="insertPhoto"),
]
```

If you want description comment in urls.py then you can do:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
'''descriptive comment here'''
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index, name="index"),
    path('photo/',views.indexPhoto, name="indexPhoto"),
    path('photo/add/',views.addPhoto, name="addPhoto"),
    path('photo/insert',views.insertPhoto, name="insertPhoto"),
]
```

Comment: is there a reason or it just how it works. cuz we can use ''' ''' in other files right?

Comment: Actually `''' '''` inside list of URLS is invalid Python syntex. You can use `''' '''` outside the list in any file.